# How do I declare what object separates anticipated arguments in a Discord bot in Python?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have been creating a discord bot in python and I have tried to give it the functionality to create a dictionary containing all of the coordinates to teleport to in my MC Server.  The user is supposed to type !add and then the title of the spot corresponding to the coordinates, followed by the actual coordinates in the discord chat, like so:

```
!add Main Building,-312 74 -31
```

I want the bot to take 2 arguments and add one as the key to the dictionary and one as the value which are separated by a comma, but right now the bot assumes that the first argument ends at the first space.  The command above would return this value in the dictionary:

```
"Main": "House"
```

How do I make the distinction that the argument's are separated by a comma?

**Here is my code that I am having issues with:**

```
@bot.command(name='add', help='Adds TP Name and TP Coordinates')
async def roll(ctx, tpName, tpCoords):
    tps[tpName] = tpCoords
    tpGroup = [
        tpName
        ,tpCoords
    ]
    await ctx.send('Adding coordinates',': '.join(tpGroup), "to the TP coordinate list")
```

Comment: Are you always getting multiple integers and a string?  You could do `roll(ctx, tpCoords: discord.Greedy[int], *, tpName)`

Answer (score 1):

Add an argument called `*`, this way both arguments can have spaces inside them with no problem, you don't need to have a comma.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to parse the args based on a comma inside the function.

You can try the following assuming your tps dict is defined:

Also, `ctx.send()` needs a formatted message.

```py
@bot.command(name='add', help='Adds TP Name and TP Coordinates')
async def roll(ctx, *, info_in=None):
    if not info_in or ',' not in info_in:
        await ctx.send('Please include coordinates in correct format')
        return
    tpName = info_in.split(',')[0]
    tpCoords = info_in.split(',')[1].lstrip()
    tps[tpName] = tpCoords
    tpGroup = [
        tpName
        , tpCoords
    ]
    msg = 'Adding coordinates' + ': '.join(tpGroup) + " to the TP coordinate list"
    await ctx.send(msg)
```

Result:

[image]